# Angular 2: Add elements to dom programmatically with viewencaptulation

Tags: css, angular

I am working on a context menu where I need to get the size of the menu and every sub menu before rendering. The way I have done this in the past is to append a element structure to the dom, compute bbox, line height, etc. And then remove it, so it will never be visible for the user.

From this operation I get everything I need to check if the menu goes outside screen, etc. Then maybe make changes to it.

In angular 2 I am able to do this if ViewEncaptulation is set to None. But I get an error in my current build setup if I use it, so I am stuck to the default value.

Does anyone know how I can make an element programmatically and make it get the same classes from inside the ViewEncaptulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking I solved it like this.

```
private elementRef: ElementRef

getEncapsulationId(): string {
    if (!this.elementRef) {
        return '';
    }

    var attr = this.elementRef.nativeElement.attributes;
    for(let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++){            
        let s = attr[i].name;
        if(s.includes('_nghost')){
            return '_ngcontent' + s.substring(7);
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

When creating the element I add the encapsulation id as an attribute.

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.setAttribute(this.getEncapsulationId, '');
element.classList.add('some-class');
```

Let me know if someone has a better solution for this problem.